# Generate url's to an unordered list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I have an unordered list that works, and it is as follow. but i need it to result in links instead of regular text.

working list:

```
    var navLinks = [
        "Eggs",
        "Milk",
        "Juice",
        "Diapers",
        "Bread"
    ];

    var ul = document.createElement("ul");

    for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
        ul.innerHTML = ul.innerHTML + "<li>" + navLinks[i] + "</li>";
    }

    document.body.appendChild(ul);
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Sarfraz and Nicola Peluchetti.
final code:

```
var navLinks = [
    "Eggs",
    "Milk",
    "Juice",
    "Diapers",
    "Bread"
];

var ul = document.createElement("ul");
var e = ".htm";
for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
    ul.innerHTML += "<li><a href='" + navLinks[i] + "" + e + "'>" + navLinks[i] + "</a></li>";
}

document.body.appendChild(ul)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
ul.innerHTML = ul.innerHTML + "<li>" + navLinks[i] + "</li>";
```

With:

```
ul.innerHTML = ul.innerHTML + "<li><a href='#'>" + navLinks[i] + "</a></li>";
```

You need to decide what value you would like to have for the `href` property of these links.

Comment: You both have it right. but i can only check answer once, but you both have it right thank you. both

Comment: ahhhh, i need the hash to be navLinks[i] plus(+) .htm

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like

```
 var navLinks = [
        "Eggs",
        "Milk",
        "Juice",
        "Diapers",
        "Bread"
    ];

    var ul = document.createElement("ul");

    for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
        ul.innerHTML = ul.innerHTML + "<li><a>" + navLinks[i] + "</a></li>";
    }

    document.body.appendChild(ul)
```

Of course you should add an `href` property to the link so that it leads somewhere

Comment: You both have it right. but i can only check answer once, but you both have it right thank you. both

Comment: ahhhh, i need the hash to be navLinks[i] plus(+) .htm